# error reading input file: Stale NFS file handle

Tags: linux, nfs

I am running a bash script on a Linux server. At the time it finished running, I got this message

```
../scripts/makepbs.sh: error reading input file: Stale NFS file handle
```

What does it mean?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your NFS server has been disconnected.

`pwd`

should reveal the full directory structure, One of those folders has been disconnected and can no longer communicate with your NFS server.

Comment: pwd says I still in the same directory as before. Looks like nothing happen?

Comment: i'd check the messages log on both servers, and remount any NFS mounts you have. (Rebooting might work as well, if the NFS mounts are setup on boot)